# Is there a name for a non-negative real-valued matrix with each row sums to a probability, i.e. a value in $[0,1]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, terminology, markov-chains

A non-negative real-valued square matrix $\bf P$ is called a **stochastic matrix** if every row of it sums to $1$, such like the transition matrix of a Markov chain. However, I am wondering if there is a name for a non-negative real-valued $\bf P$ with "weaker" condition that each row sums to a value in $[0,1]$ (i.e. the summation is not necessarily $1$)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call it "substochastic". I just made up that word, but then I searched Google and people do seem to be using it with exactly this definition.